# How to check if a button hasn't been clicked in a certain amount of time (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am making a story kind of html page where you anger the narrator by pressing "t". He says "I bet you can't go a full 5 seconds without pressing t."

Anyone know how I could check if a button isn't clicked within 5 seconds, and if it is clicked make something else happen as well.

I tried to use seconds to solve this problem, as I am very new to JavaScript, this is currently being worked on.

```
  function timenow() {
    var now = today.getSeconds();
  }
  function timelater() {
    var later = today.getSeconds();
  }



  function clicked() {
    if (!document.getElementById("form-search") && document.getElementById("fake-search").value == "t") {
      if (a==8) {
        alert("Alright Smart Guy, lets just delete everything on the page!");
        document.body.style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("google_search").style.cursor= "wait";
        a+=1;
      }
      else if (a==9) {
        alert("You know what... I'm done, I'm Done! If you can not press t for 5 seconds, I'll give you everything back.");
        a+=1;
        timenow();
        setTimeout(timelater(), 5000);
        console.log(now);
        console.log(later);
      }
    else {
      null;
    }
```

Comment: 'I like simplicity' I like structured questions but you havent provided one here...

Comment: `I am fairly new to JavaScript and I like simplicity, please consider this while answering` - having cake and eating it, too. You can remove that line, and leave the rest.

Comment: Okay, I just didn't want people thinking that I was some master and that I understood everything about css and html and javascript :I

Comment: Generally questions are better accepted here when they include some code that prove the asking person gave it a shot first.  Now you know for next time. :)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should have some of your own effort and problem with that to solve not just like asking someone for the  whole code.

Answer (score 3):

First, you would use [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to start a timer as soon as the button is displayed (In this case, on page load).  Second, we will use [onClick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) to call a function when the button is pressed.  If the button is pressed, we call [clearTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) so that the timeout code doesn't run.  If the button is not pressed, the timeout will expire and the timeout code will run.

```js
//first we define what happens when the button is not pressed in time.
function notPressed() {
  alert("You didn't press the button!!!");
}

//next we define what happens if the button IS pressed in time.
function pressed() {
  alert("You pressed the button!");
  //Here we must clear the timer or it will run even after the button is pressed!
  clearTimeout(btnTimer); 
}

//finally we start the timer.  We specify the time using milliseconds in the second parameter.
var btnTimer = window.setTimeout(notPressed,5000);
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="pressed()" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this out

Comment: Updated to make the code a bit more straight forward.

Comment: I also just noticed you meant a key press, not a button click.  See if you can figure that out yourself with some googling.  If you can't, please ask another question.  Be sure to include what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You'd first make a placeholder for your timer and initialize it through a click event handler. Anytime between the 5s you check whether the key `t` has been pressed **and** if the timer is still going. Within that conditional you provide further functionality.

**UPDATE:** To assign the same functionality to `keyup` and `keypress` events, simply extract the callback into its' own function `detectKey` and pass that function into both event handlers:

```js
let timer;

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', () => {
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    alert("Time's up! You didn't press the letter");
  }, 5000);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', detectKey);

document.addEventListener('keypress', detectKey);

function detectKey(e) {
  const key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase() === 't';
  
  if (key && timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    
    timer = null;
        
    alert('You pressed the letter!');    
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: This is what I needed, I just like to understand it all before I actually put it in my code. Can you add some comments? Thanks

Comment: @ConlanRyan I've added the connects as requested. Let me know if everything looks okay.

Comment: Much MUCH better! I understand it perfectly now! Thank you all so much!

Comment: I will also try and figure out key press for this as well. It will be difficult because of the if statements and time, whatever,

Comment: I've got you covered on that. Check my updated answer.